# jquery ui tabs active link css parent background transition

Tags: jquery, css, background, tabs, transition

I'm using jquery tabs as my primary navigation and what I'm trying to achieve with css transitions is a parent background picture will change its size when a button of the ui tab links is active. So you click on lets say 'GALLERY' box-bg background will animate and stay on the links active.

Here is abit of the html for the tabs

```
<div class="box-bg">
    <div id="box">
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul class="ui-tab-block">
                <li style="height:60px; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);"></li>
                <li class="ui-prim-nav"><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
                <li class="ui-prim-nav"><a href="#gallery">GALLERY</a></li>
                <li class="ui-prim-nav"><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li class="ui-prim-nav"><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li style="height:170px; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my background

```
.box-bg{

    background:url(../img/bg_placeholder.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 1000px 666px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-out;

    transition: background-size 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-size 2s ease-in-out;
    -web-kit-transition: background-size 2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-size 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

My css transition

```
li.ui-tabs-active a:active .box-bg{
    -webkit-animation-name: bg-size;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-delay: .5s;

    -moz-animation-name: bg-size;
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-animation-delay: .5s;

    -o-animation-name: bg-size;
    -o-animation-duration: 2s;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -o-animation-delay: .5s;
}
@keyframes bg-size {
  0% {
      background-size:1000px 666px;
  }
  100% {
      background-size:2000px 1333px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bg-size {
  0% {
     background-size:1000px 666px;
  }
  100% {
     background-size:2000px 1333px;
  }
}
```

here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sionts/UytVn/) of what I'm doing I've scrapped the css aniamtion for now seeing if i can do it with jquery .

Sorry its a lot to look at, but thanks for looking at it in advance.

Comment: Because `a:active`, your tab will only animate on mousedown only. Lifting up mouse button it'll animate back. I don't think you wanted to use that... Also i would suggest you to use JSFiddle, we can help you better with live examples...